# No metadata for Entity was found

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, node-oracledb

##### Project informations:

- Nest.js

  - @nestjs/typerom v9.0.1
- oracledb 5.5.0
- typeorm v0.3.15
- Windows 10
- Node v16.18.0
- Npm v9.4.2

##### Error log:

```
[Nest] 24652  - 16/05/2023 13:07:45   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] No metadata for "Atendente" was found.
EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "Atendente" was found.
```

```
{
  "statusCode": 500,
  "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

##### Others logs:

```
sei database using logging = true:
query: SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','DB_NAME') AS "db_name" FROM dual
query: SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','DB_NAME') AS "db_name" FROM dual

pad database using logging = true: 
query: SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_SCHEMA') AS "schema_name" FROM dual
query: SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_SCHEMA') AS "schema_name" FROM dual
```

##### Project Structure

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#multiple-databases
Following docs, I have a default db as sei.database.ts with no name given:

```
// src/database/sei.database.ts
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

export const seiDatabase: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: 'oracle',
  host: process.env.SEI_CONNECTION_STRING_PROD,
  port: 1521,
  username: process.env.SEI_ORACLE_USER_PROD,
  password: process.env.SEI_ORACLE_PWD_PROD,
  sid: process.env.SEI_CONNECTION_SID_PROD,
  entities: [__dirname + '/../sei/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  synchronize: false,
  logging: true,
};
```

A second db named `pad`:

```
// /src/database/pad.database.ts
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

export const padDatabase: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  name: 'pad',
  type: 'oracle',
  host: process.env.PAD_CONNECTION_STRING_PROD,
  port: 1521,
  username: process.env.PAD_ORACLE_USER_PROD,
  password: process.env.PAD_ORACLE_PWD_PROD,
  sid: process.env.PAD_CONNECTION_SID_PROD,
  entities: [__dirname + '/../pad/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  synchronize: false,
  logging: true,
};
```

On my `app.module.ts`:

```
// /src/app.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

import { DatabaseModule } from './database/database.module';

import { UsuariosModule } from './sei/usuarios/usuarios.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    DatabaseModule,
    AtendentesModule,
    UsuariosModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

my Atendente module `atendentes.module.ts`:

```
// /src/pad/atendentes.module.ts:
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

import { AtendentesController } from './atendentes.controller';
import { AtendentesService } from './atendentes.service';
import { Atendente } from './entities/atendente.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Atendente])],
  controllers: [AtendentesController],
  providers: [AtendentesService],
})
export class AtendentesModule {}
```

My Usuario module `usuarios.module.ts`:

```
// src/sei/usuarios.module.ts
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

import { UsuariosController } from './usuarios.controller';
import { UsuariosService } from './usuarios.service';
import { Usuario } from './entities/usuario.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Usuario])],
  controllers: [UsuariosController],
  providers: [UsuariosService],
})
export class UsuariosModule {}
```

My `usuarios.module.ts` is working because apparently it is pulling from the default data source, however, my `atendentes.module.ts` does not receive the connection because I could not set up the connection correctly and cannot find the error.

Update:
My connection is only being established on the database that is listed without the name (by default), if I change pad.database.ts and remove the name it connects (need to add a name property to sei.database.ts so that the file is ignored).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the name of the data source as the second parameter when you register the entities in the `forFeature` method, unless is the default data source (the one without a name).

```js
// /src/pad/atendentes.module.ts:
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

import { AtendentesController } from './atendentes.controller';
import { AtendentesService } from './atendentes.service';
import { Atendente } from './entities/atendente.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Atendente], 'pad')],
  controllers: [AtendentesController],
  providers: [AtendentesService],
})
export class AtendentesModule {}
```

Inside the service, it's needed to also pass the data source name to the `InjectRepository` decorator

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import type { Repository } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class AtendentesService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(Atendente, 'pad') private readonly repo: Repository<Atendente>) {}
}
```

Comment: This way, I got the following error: ```Nest cannot resolve the dependencies of AttendantsService (?). Please make sure that the argument AtendenteRepository in index [0] is available in the context of AttendantsModule.

Possible solutions:
- Is the AtendentesModule a valid NestJS module?
- If the AtendentesRepository is a provider, is it part of the current AtendentesModule?
- If the AtendentesRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within the AtendentesModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the module containing the AtendenteRepository */ ]
  }) ```

Comment: @LucasMarra as the docs says you need to pass the data source to the decorators besides the entity itself, I updated my answer to point that

Comment: That worked like a charm!
So I need to pass data source for every service I'm using, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the way